# JavaScript alert does not work correctly with div tag

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

There are 16 boxes in html.

```
<div id="box-container">
    <div class="box" data-coord="0:0" style="clear: left"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="0:1"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="0:2"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="0:3"></div>
    <div class="box" data-coord="1:0" style="clear: left"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="1:1"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="1:2"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="1:3"></div>
    <div class="box" data-coord="2:0" style="clear: left"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="2:1"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="2:2"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="2:3"></div>
    <div class="box" data-coord="3:0" style="clear: left"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="3:1"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="3:2"></div> <div class="box" data-coord="3:3"></div>
</div>
```

I want to write js code that will do following:
When I click on any box, it will alert it's order number from 1 to 16.
There is my js code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var boxArray = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
    for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
        boxArray[i].onclick = function () {
            var say = function (i) {
                alert(i);
            };
            say(i);
        }
    }
</script>
```

But every time it alerts **16**.
What is the problem?
Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 4):

Using the classical [IIFE: Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) you can write:

```js
var boxArray = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
  boxArray[i].onclick = (function (i) {
    return function (e) {
      var say = function (i) {
        alert(i);
      };
      say(i);
    };
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
    <div class="box" data-coord="0:0" style="clear: left">1</div> <div class="box" data-coord="0:1">2</div> <div class="box" data-coord="0:2">3</div> <div class="box" data-coord="0:3">4</div>
    <div class="box" data-coord="1:0" style="clear: left">5</div> <div class="box" data-coord="1:1">6</div> <div class="box" data-coord="1:2">7</div> <div class="box" data-coord="1:3">8</div>
    <div class="box" data-coord="2:0" style="clear: left">9</div> <div class="box" data-coord="2:1">10</div> <div class="box" data-coord="2:2">11</div> <div class="box" data-coord="2:3">12</div>
    <div class="box" data-coord="3:0" style="clear: left">13</div> <div class="box" data-coord="3:1">14</div> <div class="box" data-coord="3:2">15</div> <div class="box" data-coord="3:3">16</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with javascript's scope. `i` is outside the scope of the for loop because you used `var`, so when you do `alert(i)`, it takes the value that `i` is left with after the loop (since the loop has already run).

Change your for loop from

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (let i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++)
```

And it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addEventListener` with a local declared variable, like this

```js
var boxArray = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
  boxArray[i].addEventListener('click', (function(e) {
    var num = i;
    return function() {
      alert(num);
    }
  })());
}
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
  <div class="box" data-coord="0:0" style="clear: left">1</div>
  <div class="box" data-coord="0:1">2</div>
  <div class="box" data-coord="0:2">3</div>
  <div class="box" data-coord="0:3">4</div>
  <div class="box" data-coord="1:0" style="clear: left">5</div>
  <div class="box" data-coord="1:1">6</div>
  <div class="box" data-coord="1:2">7</div>
  <div class="box" data-coord="1:3">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this so much simpler if you use jQuery's `.index()`

It's as simple as doing this:

```
$(".box").click(function(){

  var i = $(this).index();     
  alert(i);

});
```

***DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zoxirafufo/edit?html,js,console,output***